# Add new record Keyboard Shortcut on Kendo Grid Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

I need to add new row on kendo grid with Batch editing using keyboard shortcut like when i press enter, new row will be added on kendo grid and the focus is set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("grid").data("kendoGrid").setOptions({ navigatable: true });
    $(document).on('keyup', '#grid', function (event) {

        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '13') { // use your key ascii code

            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.addRow();
        }
    });
```